# How to return multiple values without using Collections?

Tags: java, string, methods, collections, return

I am using textbook Murach's java programming, and in one of the exercises, it is asking me to do the following:

> add this method (given by the book):
>
> ```
> private static String displayMultiple(Displayable d, int count)
> ```
>
> write the code for this method so it **returns a String** that contains the Displayable parameter the number of times specified by the int parameter.
>
> `Displayable` is an interface that implements `getDisplayText()`. And this method just returns a `String` with instance variables of an object, i.e. for an Employee, it returns first name, last name, department, and salary.

Everything works, except for the "**returns a String**".

Comment: ...That description makes absolutely no sense. Aside from that, could you provide the code you have so far? It may or may not help us answer.

Comment: I understand the exercise like this: Let `d` be an instance of `Displayable` such that `d.getDisplayText()` would return `"ho"`.  Then `displayMultiple(d, 3)` is supposed to return the string `"hohoho"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it:

```
private static String displayMultiple(Displayable d, int count){
   String s = "";
   String ss = d.getDisplayText();
   for(int i=0; i<count; i++){
      s += ss;
   }
   return s;
}
```

Comment: I think this is it! I am retarded for thinking it was asking to return that String three times. That's not possible, right? Thank you!

Comment: Avoid concatenating strings inside loops using `+` operator since it each times has to create new instance of string which by copying old string and adding new one. Use `StringBuilder` instead and its `append` method to store data you want to be in string. Then when you are done simply call `toString` on builder to get your result.

Answer (score 6):

This is probably an exercise about loops:

- You have a way to convert `d` to a string: `getDisplayText`. This yields, say, `"ABCD"`
- You want to return `count` times that string `"ABCD"`. If `count == 3`, that means `"ABCDABCDABCD"`.

Useful keywords: `for loop`, [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). Here is a template that you can use to get started:

```
String text = ;// Use getDisplayText here
StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder();
/* Loop from 0 to count - 1 */ {
    // Append `text` to `ret` 
}
return ret.toString();
```

You don't actually need to return multiple values.

Comment: Thank you, this also makes sense! Although the book hasn't taught us about StringBuilder class yet. It's coming up in two chapters though!

Comment: The problem with using `+=` is that it may behave badly for large values of `count`; in this simple case you may be fine, but using `+=` in a loop is a bit of an anti-pattern (`+=` creates a new string every time, so in the `ABCD` example you end up creating `ABCD`, then `ABCDABCD`, then `ABCDABCDABCD`, and so on; this is wasteful)

Comment: How is that different than appending in a loop to a StringBuilder object?

Comment: `StringBuilder` does it efficiently (you only create one stringbuilder that grows, no `count` distinct stringbuilders) :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return multiple values with out using collection then you can create an Class -

```
public class MultipleValue{

   String firstValue;
   String secondValue;

   //other fields

}
```

Then from `someMethod()` where you want to return multiple value (that is `firstValue`, `secondValue`) you can do this -

```
public MultipleValue someMethod(){

   MultipleValue mulVal = new MultipleValue();
   mulVal.setFirstValue("firstValue");
   mulVal.setSecondValue("secondVAlue");

   return mulVal;
}
```

Then from the calling class of `someMethod()` you can extract multiple values (that is `firstValue` and `secondValue`) like this -

```
//from some calling method
MultipleValue mulVals = someMethod();

String firstValue = mulVals.getFirstValue();
String secondValue = mulVals.getSecondValue();
```

Comment: Could I return an object of class MultipleValue multiple times this way?

Comment: In this case you need to call `someMethod()` multiple time